# How to use reauthenticateWithCredential without asking the password?

Tags: flutter

I create a widget on which my user can edit his email, but I need to use "reauthenticateWithCredential" to make it works.

But how can I use reauthenticateWithCredential without asking my user to enter his password again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use to use firebase for that it has own example code for that, it working and does not asking password again. In some case when your users token has expired, your authantication maneger has to do that automaticly(reAuth).

"Linking/re-authentication with email link#" read this headline in following link.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/email-link-auth